# Regex pattern for validation - trying to condense repetitive patterns in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have to validate a "project code" string in C# - the string length can be anywhere between 5-10 characters.  The only rules outside this are as follows:

1. First character can only be a letter or number
2. Middle characters if they exist can be letter, number or a period (.)
3. Last character can only be a letter or number
4. *Avoid more than one period in a row in the middle

I can validate the 5-10 characters restriction like this:

```
^(?=.{5,10}$)
```

And part 1 and part 3 like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}
```

The middle rule is looking like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.]{0,8}
```

And if I put it all together I have this:

```
^(?=.{5,10}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.]{0,8}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}$
```

It works fine, but with all that nearly identical code, it seems it could be condensed somehow.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to allow ASCII only symbols?

Comment: Restricted a bit further than that - just the 26 letters of the English alphabet or digits 0-9

Comment: Then you have an answer.

Comment: Sorry - can anyone figure out how to avoid multiple periods in a row in the middle part?  So 123.45 is fine and 12.34.5 is fine but 123..45 is not?

Comment: Just add a lookahead: `(?i)^(?!.*[.]{2})[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]{3,8}[a-z0-9]$`.

Comment: Oh my god - thank you so much - I couldn't get the syntax of the lookahead right.

Comment: This will work, too: `(?i)^(?=.{5,10}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9.]+)*$`.  The lookahead handles all the counting, so the main body of the regex only has to validate  the structure (i.e., that every period is preceded and followed by alphnumerics, and there are no other kinds of characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)^(?!.*[.]{2})[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]{3,8}[a-z0-9]$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fi)%5E(%3F!.*%5B.%5D%7B2%7D)%5Ba-z0-9%5D%5Ba-z0-9.%5D%7B3%2C8%7D%5Ba-z0-9%5D%5Cr%3F%24&i=12.34.5%0D%0A123..45%0D%0A15.456.78&o=m)

- `^[a-z0-9]` - *First character can only be a letter or number*
- `[a-z0-9.]{3,8}` - *Middle characters if they exist can be letter, number or a period (`.`)*
- `[a-z0-9]$` - *Last character can only be a letter or number*
- `^(?!.*[.]{2})` - **Avoid more than one period in a row in the middle*

The `(?i)` inline modifier can be replaced with [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) when used with the `new Regex()` initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a bit shorter by matching the middle part 3 to 8 times, and a single time with the outer parts (You don't need {1}). This eliminates the need for the 5,10 part of your code because 1+3+1=5 and 1+8+1=10.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.]{3,8}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Comment: Oh that's right - thanks!  Over-constructed a bit there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to piggy-back off Cyral's answer so +1 to him!
I'm using a case insensitive flag to get from `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `[a-z0-9]`

```
^(?i)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]{3,8}[a-z0-9]$
```

Thanks folks!